# What is MILAIP referenced in International Notams?

Tags: international, notam

When looking at notams on the DAIP. There is a line referencing a publication or website I cannot find.

ATS COMMUNICATION FACILITIES.
TWR SERVICE LIMITED DUE TO 'SIGONELLA GROUND' NOT PROVIDED.
REF MILAIP AD 2 LICZ 1-11. 1700-0700, 01 MAR 17:00 2024 UNTIL 29 MAR 07:00
2024. CREATED: 01 MAR 14:57 2024

What is MILAIP AD 2 LICZ 1-11 and where can I find it?

Comment: AFOD [MIL AIP links](https://www.afod.eur.army.mil/Links/)

Answer (score 2):

MILAIP = Military Aeronautical Information Publication.

You wouldn't normally have access to these unless you are active duty.  If you have a need to fly into Sigonella you should call and get a copy.

Comment: Some MIL AIP's are publically available. For example Netherlands: https://english.defensie.nl/topics/milaip-military-aeronautical-information-publication and Denmark: http://www.flv.dk/milaim/milaip_online.html